# Why does my custom iterator require a call operator in range based for loops?

Tags: c++, ranged-loops

Link to the [mcve](http://rextester.com/KMFO62253).

We define a matrix to be iterable both by rows and by columns. Here's the implementation of the row-wise iterator:

```
template<class Real>
class RowIterator {
public:
    RowIterator() { }
    RowIterator(Real* begin, size_t rows, size_t cols) : begin(begin), rows(rows), cols(cols) { }

    Real* operator*() const { return begin; }
    Real& operator[](size_t col) const { return begin[col]; }

    bool operator!=(const RowIterator& it) const { return begin != it.begin; }
    RowIterator& operator++() { begin += cols; --rows; return *this; }

private:
    Real* begin;
    size_t rows, cols;
};
```

Iterating over our matrix is implemented using a `Range` object define as follows:

```
namespace details
{

template<class Iterator>
struct Range {
    Iterator begin, end;
    Range() { }
    Range(Iterator begin, Iterator end) : begin(begin), end(end) { }
};

template<class Iterator>
Iterator begin(const Range<Iterator>& range) { return range.begin; }
template<class Iterator>
Iterator end(const Range<Iterator>& range) { return range.end; }

}

using details::Range;
template<class Iterator>
Range<Iterator> make_range(Iterator begin, Iterator end) { return Range<Iterator>(begin, end); }
```

This is basically our usage code:

```
Range<RowIterator<float>> make_row_range(float* mat, size_t rows, size_t cols) {
    return make_range(
        RowIterator<float>(mat, rows, cols),
        RowIterator<float>(mat + rows * cols, 0, cols));
}

int main() {
    size_t rows = 4, cols = 6;
    float* mat = new float[rows * cols];
    for(size_t i = 0; i < rows * cols; ++i)
        mat[i] = (float)i;
    auto rowrange = make_row_range(mat, rows, cols);

    // this loop works as expected
    std::cout << "begin, end" << std::endl;
    for(auto b = begin(rowrange), e = end(rowrange); b != e; ++b) {
        // using RowIterator<T>::operator[](size_t)
        std::cout << "start of row: " << b[0] << std::endl;
    }

    // this loop produces confusing compiler errors
    std::cout << "range based" << std::endl;
    for(auto row : rowrange) {                        // this is line 42
        // row is of type float*
        std::cout << "start of row: " << row[0] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled the above MCVE and got the following compiler errors:

- Visual Studio 2013 (all on line 42):

  ```
  error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments
  error C3536: '$S2': cannot be used before it is initialized
  error C3536: '$S3': cannot be used before it is initialized
  error C2100: illegal indirection
  error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'float *'
  ```
- GCC 5.1 (on line 42):

  ```
  error: no match for call to '(RowIterator<float>) ()'
  ```
- Clang 3.7.0 (on line 42):

  ```
  error: type 'RowIterator<float>' does not provide a call operator
  note: when looking up 'begin' function for range expression of type 'details::Range<RowIterator<float> >'
  ```

All compilers are searching for a call operator. **Why?** [As I understand](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), the above iterator provides the minimal interface for ranged loops [and it works when using the syntactical equivalence code from *cppreference.com*](http://rextester.com/KMFO62253).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While writing this question I came up with the solution (*rubber SO debugging*?): the compiler first checks for the members `Range::begin` and `Range::end` and tries to invoke those leading to the missing call operator. None of the tested compilers indicated this clearly in their error messages[1]. The fix is to simply rename them:

```
namespace range
{

template<class Iterator>
struct Range {
    // "begin" and "end" have ultra-special meaning in this context!!!
    Iterator range_begin, range_end;
    Range() { }
    Range(Iterator begin, Iterator end) : range_begin(begin), range_end(end) { }
};

template<class Iterator>
Iterator begin(const Range<Iterator>& range) { return range.range_begin; }
template<class Iterator>
Iterator end(const Range<Iterator>& range) { return range.range_end; }

}
```

The requirements on class `Range` are well defined (source: *cppreference.com*, emphasis mine):

> *begin_expr* and *end_expr* are defined as follows:
>
> 1 If *range_expression* is an expression of array type, then
>   *begin_expr* is `__range` and *end_expr* is  `(__range + __bound)`, where `__bound` is the number of elements in the array (if the array
>   has unknown size or is of an incomplete type, the program is
>   ill-formed)
>
> **2 If *range_expression* is an expression of a class type C that has a
>   member named `begin` and/or a member named `end` (regardless of the
>   type or accessibility of such member), then *begin_expr* is
>   `__range.begin()` and  *end_expr* is `__range.end()`;**
>
> 3 Otherwise, *begin_expr* is `begin(__range)` and *end_expr* is
>   `end(__range)`, which are found via argument-dependent lookup (non-ADL
>   lookup is not performed).

[1]: Clang actually came close, though even its message is ambiguous: I thought it was (adl) looking up `details::begin(Range)` instead it was looking straight at `Range::begin`.